# Update a button from another class

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to write a python program and I want to be able to update a button from a another class when it is clicked. eg:

The gui.py file:

```
class main(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, background="white")   

        self.parent = parent

        self.initUI()
        #menu bar
        menu = Menu(parent)
        parent.config(menu=menu)
        parent.option_add('*tearOff', FALSE)
        #file menu
        fileMenu = Menu(menu)
        menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=fileMenu)
        fileMenu.add_command(label="New Show", command=shows.saves.open)
        fileMenu.add_command(label="Save Show", command=shows.saves.save)
        fileMenu.add_command(label="Save Show As", command=shows.saves.saveas)
        fileMenu.add_separator()
        fileMenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=self.quit)
        #edit menu
        editMenu = Menu(menu)
        menu.add_cascade(label="Edit", menu=editMenu)
        editMenu.add_command(label="Copy (ctrl+c)", command=shows.saves.open)
        editMenu.add_command(label="Cut (ctrl+x)", command=shows.saves.save)
        editMenu.add_command(label="Paste (ctrl+v)", command=shows.saves.saveas)
        #insert menu
        insrtMenu = Menu(menu)
        menu.add_cascade(label="Insert", menu=insrtMenu)
        insrtMenu.add_command(label="Add Audo Cue (ctrl + 1)", command=shows.saves.open)
        insrtMenu.add_command(label="Add Memo Cue (ctrl + 2)", command=shows.saves.save)

        #toolbar
        toolbar = Frame(parent)
        b1 = Button(toolbar, text="Mode = Setup", command=m.mode.switch)
        b1.pack(side=LEFT, padx=2, pady=2)
        b2 = Button(toolbar, text="Preview", command=shows.saves.open)
        b2.pack(side=LEFT, padx=2, pady=2)
        b3 = Button(toolbar, text="Edit", command=shows.saves.open)
        b3.pack(side=LEFT, padx=2, pady=2)
        b4 = Button(toolbar, text="Edit", command=shows.saves.open)
        b4.pack(side=LEFT, padx=2, pady=2)
        toolbar.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)


        #main table
        screen_width = parent.winfo_screenwidth()
        screen_height = parent.winfo_screenheight()
        listbox = Listbox(parent, width=screen_width, height=screen_height, bg="black", fg="white")
        listbox.pack()

        listbox.insert(END, "Cue1 - Rain")
    def initUI(self):

        self.parent.title("PyCue ALPHA 0.1")
        #self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
```

the m.py file:

```
class mode():
    def switch():
        if b1["text"] == "Mode = Setup":
            b1["text"] = "Mode = Run"
        else:
            b1["text"] = "Mode = Setup"
```

Could someone please explain how I could go about doing this?
All my (very alpha) code is on github: https://github.com/codefail/PyCue if you want to view the whole thing.

Comment: What's wrong with what you have?  Do you get a traceback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to make `switch` a staticmethod:

```
class mode():
    @staticmethod
    def switch(b1):
        if b1["text"] == "Mode = Setup":
            b1["text"] = "Mode = Run"
        else:
            b1["text"] = "Mode = Setup"
```

You also need some way of passing the button to the callback -- which you can't do by passing `callback` to the constructor.  You'll need to do it in 2 lines:

```
b1 = Button(toolbar, text="Mode = Setup")
b1.config(command=lambda : m.mode.switch(b1))
```

Although, I really don't see the need for a class (`mode`) here.  You don't seem to be using an instance, and therefore you're not really sharing any data ... It seems like you could just use a `switch` *function* and get rid of the `mode` class entirely.